# English translation of SS officer’s line in Fury

Tags: dialogue, fury

What was this SS officer saying during this scene in Fury? There was no English subtitle for his line (around 1:41:38).

I do not know German so I cannot transcribe what he says. A minute later after the officer speaks, one of the SS soldiers opens the hatch, and Norman shoots at him with his submachine gun. Then Wardaddy and his crew open fire on the SS battalion that was marching towards the Americans’ supply area in the rear past the crossroads.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My German is, as best, rusty... so If anyone speaks it better, feel free to correct me.

As the German soldiers are approaching the tanks, there's a lot along the lines of "get on with it" and "hurry up". It doesn't really say much, probably a bit of ad-libbing, just the sense of urgency.

Just before the first soldiers climb up to the tank, after the line "Come on in", it's "Get on the broken tank" - "auf den kaputten panzer darauf", I think.

Then the arm-waving bit that the photo above comes from - this is the bit I'm least clear on, but I'm hearing "Zweiter unserer dazug" which frankly breaks my schoolboy German. My best guess is something along the lines of "our second effort", but that doesn't really make any sense to me either.

If it's "da such" then it could be something more like "search both". Alternatively, "zug" is a military term, meaning "platoon", which might mean "our second platoon" as a kind of supportive cheer.

Comment: The first 3 paragraphs are spot on. Regarding the rest: it's 'zweiter und dritter Zug! *stop-gesture*' - Just meaning that the second and third Platoon are ordered to stop. See also my answer.

Comment: Cool. Glad we could get a native speaker on the case. You can tell my schoolboy German is a bit rusty;)

Answer (score 5):

The SS officer is saying/shouting a bunch of short one liners/commands in that scene:

```
Von oben bis unten,
wird alles durchsucht!
Jeder Baum!
Macht schon, macht schon
Von oben, unten
Kommt schon
Weiter!
Schneller!
Macht auf!
Weiter, weiter, weiter!
[schwer zu verstehen, in etwa: Los!]
Auf den kaputten Panzer drauf!
Zweiter und dritter Zug! [Haltegeste]
[schwer zu verstehen, in etwa: Vielleicht sind die da] immer noch drin!
Beeilt euch!
[SS soldier opens the hatch, Norman shoots]
Alarm!
```

Translated to english (as closely as possible):

```
Turn everything up and down
Everything is gonna be searched!
Every tree!
Do it already, do it!
Up and down!
Come on
Forward!
Faster!
Catch up!
Forward, forward, forward!
[hardly audible, something like: Let's go!]     
Get on the broken tank!
Second and third platoon! [fist-pump stop gesture]
[hardly audible, something like: Perhaps they are still] inside!
Hurry up!
[SS soldier opens the hatch, Norman shoots]
Alarm!
```

(yes, I'm a German native speaker)

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wikia](http://furymovie.wikia.com/wiki/Fury_Script) and official script on [SonyPictures](http://www.sonypictures.com/movies/fury/awards/scripts/fury_script.pdf) this is the translation.

```
87.
                     CONTINUED:
                     LIEUTENANT
                     (GERMAN)
      Reinhold, take your men and clear those
      structures. Hoehner, ensure the enemy
      tank is unoccupied.
```

Which agrees with the events took place after his command.

After which I guess he said **Stoppt den zweiten Zug** which means **stop second platoon.**

Comment: I'm guessing that was the pre-shoot script. There's a lot of the English dialog missing too, through this section, though the main elements up to it are there, the naming of Machine etc.

Comment: & no, he definitely doesn't say 'stoppt den zweiten zug'. My German is bad, but my ears are fine ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin: I was not able to make out entirely so I guessed based on his actions. Also *zug* means train which pretty much goes well with his action ( swinging both hands up and down ). For example [Sheldon cooper playing with trains](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jCNrs23r4DA)

Comment: The 2 sentences roughly summarize what is happening, but it isn't something the SS officer is saying in it's dialog. The SS officer's shouts some short orders (without mentioning any names) to the effect of clearing the vicinity and checking the tank for enemy soldiers. In that context, Zug really translates to platoon. And not to train. Train doesn't make sense here - i.e. there is no train, there are no tracks. The gesture is a stop gesture - for the platoons.